# I'm looking to match quite a lot of US companies to their NAICS codes without having to manually search it up

Tags: data-request, business

I know it can be done manually through the NAICS website but I have over 3000 companies and I need to get their NAICS codes. So I'm looking for a database or anything else which I can download.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Relativity6 API service to classify business with NAICs, just using business name and address. The system will perform a real-time consulting with the help of an IA to classify the business.

https://www.relativity6.com/

Disclaimer: I work for Relativity6.